# Get Repository object for remote address

Tags: java, git, jgit

I try to obtain a `Repository` object from a URL address, with JGit using code like this:

```
Repository repository = Git.lsRemoteRepository()
    .setHeads(true)
    .setTags(true)
    .setRemote(url)
    .setCredentialsProvider(credentials)
    .getRepository();
```

However, with that code, `repository` is `null`. On the other hand, using this code

```
Collection<Ref> refs = Git.lsRemoteRepository()
    .setHeads(true)
    .setTags(true)
    .setRemote(urlString)
    .setCredentialsProvider(credentials)
    .call();
```

a collection of Ref objects can be obtained, and that method seems to work for a remote URL.

Can I obtain a Repository object from a Ref object? How can I find a file from starting from Ref object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Repository` class of JGit represents a local repository, quite often a clone of a remote repository.

The `LsRemoteCommand` returned by `Git::lsRemoteRepository` operates outside the context of a local repository and hence returns `null` for `getRepository`.

A `Ref` in JGit does not have a reference to the repository, either, as they may originate from a repository without a local representation. Remember, for example, there is no local repository for the refs returned by `LsRemoteCommand`.

To do anything useful with a repository, it needs to be cloned first. For example, with:

```java
Git git = Git.cloneRepository().setURI(url).call();
// do something with repository, access to repository through git.getRepostory()
git.close();
```

The code is equivalent to `git clone <url>`. If the url is `https://host.org/repo.git`, the command would create a clone in a `repo` subdirectory of the current working directory.

More details on cloning repositories with JGit can be found here: https://www.codeaffine.com/2015/11/30/jgit-clone-repository/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String repoUrl = "https://github.com/GovindParashar136/SpringBootWithRestOpenIdClientAuthentication.git";
String cloneDirectoryPath = "/path/to/directory/"; // Ex.in windows c:\\gitProjects\SpringBootWithRestOpenIdClientAuthentication\
try {
    System.out.println("Cloning "+repoUrl+" into "+repoUrl);
    Git.cloneRepository()
        .setURI(repoUrl)
        .setDirectory(Paths.get(cloneDirectoryPath).toFile())
        .setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("username", "password"))
        .call();
    System.out.println("Completed Cloning");
} catch (GitAPIException e) {
    System.out.println("Exception occurred while cloning repo");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```